# Get cookies from HttpsURLConnection and set them in servlet response

Tags: java, cookies

All of the following is code within a servlet, therefore there are: `HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response`

I am trying to get the cookies from https://test.com and set the exact same cookies as the servlet response (note: this is not a cross-domain page)

```
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL("https://test.com").openConnection();

conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); 
conn.setRequestMethod("GET"); 
conn.setUseCaches(false);


String s = conn.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");
if( s != null ) {
    response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", java.net.URLDecoder.decode(s, "UTF-8"));
}

conn.disconnect();
```

Using Chrome's debug tool, I show that the Set-Cookie response header is being set but the cookies themselves are not.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is your code to set the cookies?

Comment: response.setHeader("set-cookie").  Since the conn is trying to set a cookie, I'm just passing the set-cookie header along

Comment: try `Cookie[] cookies= request.getCookies() ` and iterate over it and set it  using `response.addCookie(Cookie cookie) ` method.

Comment: As Brinal mentioned try iterating cookies object and set but what are you trying to achieve through this ? what are those cookies ? session ids ? If session ids it would mean nothing to `https://test.com`